# Are forex prints less popular in the US than in Europe?

Tags: printing

When looking to show pictures at small exhibits, one printing option is to have photos printed on Forex. Forex seems quite popular in Europe, however in the US, prices for Forex printing seem to be much higher. Is Forex less popular in the US than in Europe?  Is there a preferred alternative that is more popular in the US?

Comment: I've tried making an edit to make the question less opinion and more factual based.  Questions on the popularity of print media should be factually supportable.

Comment: Forex is a specific brand of foam/plastic boards for printing on. There are similar things from a number of other companies, which may be cheaper or easier to find.

Comment: @vclaw Can you give me some suggestions/names of materials?

Comment: A more generic name would be "foam board" or "foam core".

Comment: @vclaw foamcore or foam board is not the same as forex.

Comment: Specifically, Forex (also called foamex) is PVC throughout. Foam board or foamcore is a sandwich of polystyrene (same material as packing peanuts) clad with stiff paper. Foamcore will not stand up to moisture, or even high humidity. Forex/foamex will withstand moisture, and can be used as signage in light-duty use (it won't stand up to repeated wind loads over time, but it will last well if flat-mounted to walls, even weather-exposed)

Comment: Foam board could include a variety of things, some PVC, some not. Maybe more specific to say "Closed-cell PVC foamboard". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-cell_PVC_foamboard

Comment: @vclaw Good point. I suppose "foam board" is generic enough to describe all sorts of things, whereas "foam core" literally implies a *core* that is clad with something.

Answer (score 1):

I usually print and mount on my own, but I never seen Forex offered by the labs that I occasionally use. They offer printing on paper of your choice and then mounting on Gator, Sintra, Dibond or unspecified foam core. In my high end lab prices range approx from $17 (foam core, Gator, Sintra, museum rag) to $44 (Dibond, acrylic mount) for 11x14".

Forex prices I found (randomly chosen EU lab) are GBP 22-28 for 20x30cm. That does not seem to be much different.

By the way, sinice you question appeared here several times without real answer, I did some reading on Forex. All the documents are silent on archival quality and photographic image quality.

Answer (score 0):

I have no proof that in the US Forex prints are less popular, but I have the impression that they are not. I am aware that canvas prints are popular there. Depends on what you need. If you have to present your artwork you should choose the one that is best for you. Most important is that it looks good! :)

Comment: Thank you for answer. My question is based on the fact that prices for forex are 3/4 times more than those in Europe, and I was wondering if it was a matter of having fewer places that can print photos on forex. Canvas used to be popular in Europe but it has lost appeal in recent years and it is rare for newer photographers to use it. This is based on personal experience though, not on market analysis.